# Making setup.py to point to local pypi repository

Tags: pyramid, setuptools, setup.py

recently i found pip2pi, which is super useful to install pip package from local pypi repo. I just followed the post here to do that http://blog.nknj.me/python-guide-to-hacking-on-an-airplane

But when I use setup tools, requires, I do not know how I can make it to use my local repo. I do not want to download the packages each time when i run "python setup.py develop". I am getting started with pyramid, and it will be helpful if i can avoid downloading packages everytime i create a new virtualenv.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is workaround:

```
$ python setup.py egg_info
```

The command above creates a directory `{PackageName}.egg-info` and places `requires.txt` file into one, but downloads nothing.  So you can use `requires.txt` file with `pip` command to install dependencies:

```
$ pip install -r {PackageName}.egg-info/requires.txt --index-url=file:///path/to/local/repo
```

After that, you can install your application without access to the internet:

```
$ python setup.py develop
```

Comment: This won't work if setup.py uses `setup_requires` which is being installed before execution of any command including `egg_info`.

Comment: What did you mean? I tested it in virtual env, which has Pyramid installed. After `egg_info` command executed, pyramid has been presented in `requires.txt`.

Comment: @Dmitry Vakhrushev This works partially, requires.txt misses the dependencies at times, which are downloaded while running setup.py develop.

Comment: @Venki Could you provide concrete example?